# Xcode 13 workspace cannot cross reference header files between projects

Tags: c++, xcode, frameworks

I am working with Xcode 13.4.1

I have a dynamic library C++ project "ADT".

I have created a workspace "Test ADT" to test it.

I have created a C++ project "tester" within the workspace.

I have added libADT as a framework to the project "tester".

When I try to compile "tester" it says it cannot find the header "table.hpp".

The funny thing is that before Xcode 13, I could just drag & drop projects into a workspace and everything would work fine.

This is one of those "Apple thingies" that drives me crazy! Things just stop working like they use to!

Can you help me?

[image: My workspace structure]

Comment: Does it work if you change the include to #include "..\ADT\table.hpp"? Since they in different folders, probably has no idea unless you give the path/include that path into the project settings.

Comment: It still didn't work. :( The projects are not in sibling directories.

What is odd is that this thing with workspaces used to work perfectly!